# OOB identifier invalid C++

Tags: c++

I seem to have an issue while compiling in VS, and everything does look valid.

```
1>c:\users\EvilDude\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\blackjackconsole\blackjackconsole\blackjackhand.h(10): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'game'
```

A simplified version of my source file:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#define vars
#define funcs

using namespace std;

class game{}; class deck8{};

class blackJackHand
{
public:
    blackJackHand(game *gameEntity, deck8 *deckEntity);
    ~blackJackHand();

protected:

    game *gameEntity;
    deck8 *deckEntity;
};
```

When I look at the code there is no IntelliSense errors (the red sqwigly lines)

Comment: For a forward declaration, try removing the `{}`.  For example, a forward declaration of game is `class game;`, look no `{}`.

Comment: There is no identifier *game* on line 10. You aren't showing the real code or you aren't showing the real error message.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever language that "public funcs:" is, that's not C++.

You meant just:

```
public:
```

and

```
protected:
```

C++'s syntax is very complicated. What's an obvious syntax error to carbon-based, oxygen-consuming life-forms may still make a little bit of sense, initially, to mere algorithms that go into a C++ compiler, but, several lines, or maybe pages later, they realize that they have sheer nonsense on their hands, and bail out complaining loudly, but by this time the actual error is just a long, distant memory.

Hence, quite often the line where the compiler claims the error is, is not really where the error is. It's a few lines above.

Comment: i actually have a blank define for them. they are in a header that i neglected to include.

Comment: No, it doesn't. After removing this extraneous fluff, the code compiles for me without any errors. This is the case of you completely failing to produce a minimal, complete, verifiable example, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve